# UINavigationBar buttons color

Tags: iphone, button, colors, uinavigationbar

How to change the color of the button in the UINavigationBar? For example, I use UINavigationBar with light gray background, and I need the buttons to be dark gray (almost black). It will be cool to have one solution for all button types, i.e. back button, button with image, button with text

thanks

Comment: Are you talking about how to do this via code or via interface builder?

Answer (score 2):

This is a terrible hack but, when placed in -viewDidAppear: method(s), it will change the background color (tint, actually) of UINavigationButtons.

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[self navigationController] navigationBar];
for (UIView *subview in [navBar subviews])
    {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UINavigationButton"])
        {
        if (![[subview title] isEqualToString:@"Done"])
            [subview setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:0.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        }
    }
```

It will *not* however change tint for UINavigationItemButtonViews - and this is what is used for the navigation back buttons. If someone finds a way to affect them, please let me know.